# HOW TO HANDLE SECRETS FOR DEPLOYMENT: CI/CD ON GCP

Tags: github, google-cloud-platform

I would love your assistance on this.

So I've got this streamlit web application developed and pushed to github that fetches predictions from a Vertex AI endpoint on GCP, and I would like to enable continuous integration on GCP's container registry, but the thing is this line in the code:

```
import os

os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = './google-creds.json'
```

I have to also push the credentials (dot) json file to github - which is not advisable, please what's a work around this situation?

I want to hide the credentials file on the repository but expose on the gcp deployment side.

Comment: Use [github secrets](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/using-secrets-in-github-actions).

Answer (score -1):

Figured out multiple ways to achieve, this. But shared whole process, particularly with Secret Manager on GCP:
https://dev.to/afrologicinsect/lets-build-your-first-ml-app-in-google-cloud-run-1ol2#NewYearNewSkills